# RDKIT in python

Tags: python, rdkit

I wanted to implement this module below, involving calculating atomic weights using `rdkit.Chem.PeriodicTable` module

This is the link to said module:
https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.PeriodicTable.html

Since the documentation is vague I'm not sure how to pass the argument.

So I did this:

```
from rdkit import Chem

print(Chem.PeriodicTable.GetAtomicWeight('C'))
```

But I am getting an error like this:

```
  ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-42-e098e56063a3> in <module>
  ----> 1 print(Chem.PeriodicTable.GetAtomicWeight('C'))

  ArgumentError: Python argument types in
      PeriodicTable.GetAtomicWeight(str)
  did not match C++ signature:
      GetAtomicWeight(RDKit::PeriodicTable {lvalue}, std::string)
      GetAtomicWeight(RDKit::PeriodicTable {lvalue}, unsigned int)
```

I am not sure how to pass the argument for this.

Answer (score 0):

As the page you linked says: `use GetPeriodicTable()`

```
from rdkit import Chem

pse = Chem.GetPeriodicTable()
print(pse.GetAtomicWeight('C'))
```

`12.011`